# C++ convert formatted string to a stream

Tags: c++, stream, printf

I'm using VS2008 C++.

As I understand it there is no way to pass something like this in a C++ stream : (without using external libraries)

```
"number " << i    <------ when i is an integer.
```

So I was looking for a better way to do this, and I all I could come up with is create a string using :

```
char fullstring = new char[10];
sprintf(fullString, "number %d", i);
.... pass fullstring to the stream  .....
delete[] fullString;
```

I know it's stupid, but is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 4):

```
std::ostringstream oss;
oss << "number " << i;
call_some_func_with_string(oss.str());
```

Answer (score 4):

Did you even bother to *try*?

```
int i = 3;
std::cout << "number " << i;
```

Works quite fine, and naturally the same should work with any stream.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
#include <sstream>
// [...]
std::ostringstream buffer;
int i = 5;
buffer << "number " << i;
std::string thestring = buffer.str(); // this is the droid you are looking for
```